# Display list of available methods for a given template

Tags: php, templates, magento, methods, mage

I used to remember a useful snippet (Magento native) that allowed me to list all available methods for a current template file.

Unfortunately I've lost is somewhere and would like to ask if there is anybody who can point me in the right direction?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without thinking too much you are probably thinking of

```
<pre><?php print_r(get_class_methods(get_class($this))); ?></pre>
```

Comment: With the major caveat that any magic "getX" methods will not be listed there.

Comment: I think this is what I've been looking for. I've used it in the past, but since then it got stuck in my mind as a Zend or Mage function. Thanks!

Comment: There might also be a Mage:: equivalent but I don't know it and I do know this way works good enough.

Comment: Actually I've seen in Magento code an equivalent of get_class_methods() and for displaying array of objects and models in Zend framework which is more efficient if it comes to memory as it compiles the result and delivers it to the output in plain text. I'll post it here as soon as I find it again :-)

Comment: Also, semi-related, my developer manual extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/alanstorm/extension/5577/developer_manual